# How to Calculate only Srinivas Hdfc Money in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

[image]

How to Calculate only Srinivas Hdfc Money in Excel

Comment: google - how to filter data in excel.

Comment: pivot table would be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use formula, following can be useful.

Enter the following formua in `Cell B19`

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$16,$A$2:$A$16,$A19,$B$2:$B$16,B$18)
```

Drag/Copy down and across(to right) as required. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Nice Answers Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try `SUMIF`

```
=SUMIF(range,"*text*",sum_range)
```

Example:

```
=SUMIF(A1:C11,"*srinivas*",D1:D11)
```

This link would be helpful: https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-cells-contain-specific-text

Comment: This is Good but Not 100%